# F# query concatenation

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am using `SqlDataConnection` data provider in F# to migrate some rows, part of that migration is to make a join between 3 tables like this, think of it as an inheritance of tables `A`, `B`, `C` where `B` and `C` inherit from `A` so the thing is I need to get is (in Linq-like):

```
        Bs.Join(As, b.PK, a.FK).Select(new {...})
.Concat(Cs.Join(As, c.PK, a.FK).Select(new {...})
```

In `F#`, the closest I got to this was:

```
 let result = seq {
     yield! query { ... }
     yield! query { ... }
 }
```

but I've been told this will produce 2 SQL queries and the overall result will be on-memory. The question being: is there a way to make this "concatenation" as a `query` computation expression without using `seq` so that all happens in a single SQL query?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `(query { ... }).Concat(query { ... })`?  As in C# you'd need to open the `System.Linq` namespace to get access to the `Concat` extension method.

Comment: @kvb it doesn't work interpreter says: Unexpected symbol '.' in binding

Comment: Sounds like you're missing parentheses somewhere or something.

Comment: I just `open System.Linq` and then `(query { simple query }).Concat(query { another simple query })` and i got the same error

Comment: This works for me: `(query { for x in [1..3].AsQueryable() do select x }).Concat(query { for y in [4..6].AsQueryable() do select y })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some example code that combines two queries using SQL `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

First, the setup. Note that I've added logging to `dbContext` so you can see what happens behind the scenes.

```
#r "System.Data.dll"
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"

open System
open System.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type sql = SqlDataConnection<connStr>

let createDbContext() = 
    let dbContext = sql.GetDataContext()
    // add logging to console
    dbContext.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out 
    dbContext 

let db = createDbContext()
let products = db.Product

let q1 = query { for x in products do select x }
let q2 = query { for y in products do select y }
```

The `Union` extension method combines queries as one query using `UNION`

```
let qUnion = q1.Union(q2)
qUnion.ToList() |> Seq.toList
```

Here's the logged output:

```
SELECT [t2].[Id], [t2].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [t0]
    UNION
    SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
```

The `Concat` extension method combines queries as one query using `UNION ALL`

```
let qConcat = q1.Concat(q2)
qConcat.ToList() |> Seq.toList
```

Here's the logged output:

```
SELECT [t2].[Id], [t2].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [t0]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
```

There's no special syntax for unions in `query` expressions, AFAIK.