# F# query expressions yield

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, computation-expression, query-expressions

I am learning `F#` and now am reading about computation expressions and query expressions to use with SQL type providers. I was doing some simple tasks and at some point needed to concatenate (Union) 2 queries, my first thought, after reading about `yield` in sequences and lists was to do the same inside a query expression like this:

```
query {
    yield! for a in db.As select { // projection }
    yield! for b in db.Bs select { // projection }
}
```

this was invalid code, then my second approach was to 'concat' them using:

```
seq {
    yield! query {...}
    yield! query {...}
}
```

or using the Linq's `Concat` function like this: `(query {...}).Concat(query {...})`. How to do it came from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178027/f-query-concatenation/33189355#33189355)'s answer

Both of the above approaches work with one difference though, using `seq` will run 2 SQL queries, and the `Concat` runs just one which is understandable.

My question then is: why isn't `yield` supported on query expressions?

---

**EDIT:**

After further investigation I got to the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323943%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and i saw the `Yield` and `YieldFrom` methods implemented, but not the `Combine` and `Delay` methods, which is even more confusing for me now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yield!` is supported to some extent in queries, and can be used where `select` normally is:

```
query { 
    for x in [5;2;0].AsQueryable() do 
    where (x > 1)
    sortBy x
    yield! [x; x-1] 
 } |> Seq.toList // [2;1;5;4]
```

However, in general you can't arbitrarily intersperse query and sequence operations, because it would be hard to define how they should compose:

```
query {
    for x in [1;2;3] do
    where (x > 1)
    while true do // error: can't use while (what would it mean?)
    sortBy x 
}
```

Likewise:

```
query {
    for x in [1;2;3] do
    where (x > 1)
    sortBy x 
    yield! ['a';'b';'c']
    yield! ['x';'y';'z'] // error
}
```

This is kind of ambiguous because it's not clear whether the second `yield!` is inside the `for` loop or is appending a set of elements afterwards.

So it's best to think of queries as queries and sequences as sequences, even though both kinds of computation expressions support some of the same operations.

Generally, query custom operators work element-wise, so expressing things like unions or concatenations are awkward because they deal with entire collections rather than individual elements.  But if you wanted to, you *can* create a query builder that added a `concat` custom operator that took a sequence, though it might feel a bit asymmetrical:

```
open System.Linq

type QB() =
    member inline x.Yield v = (Seq.singleton v).AsQueryable()
    member inline x.YieldFrom q = q
    [<CustomOperation("where", MaintainsVariableSpace=true)>]
    member x.Where(q:IQueryable<_>, [<ProjectionParameter>]c:Expressions.Expression<System.Func<_,_>>) = q.Where(c)
    [<CustomOperation("sortBy", MaintainsVariableSpace=true)>]
    member x.SortBy(q:IQueryable<_>, [<ProjectionParameter>]c:Expressions.Expression<System.Func<_,_>>) = q.OrderBy(c)
    [<CustomOperation("select")>]
    member x.Select(q:IQueryable<_>, [<ProjectionParameter>]c:Expressions.Expression<System.Func<_,_>>) = q.Select(c)
    [<CustomOperation("concat")>]
    member x.Concat(q:IQueryable<_>, q') = q.Concat(q')
    member x.For(q:IQueryable<'t>, c:'t->IQueryable<'u>) = q.SelectMany(fun t -> c t :> seq<_>) // TODO: implement something more reasonable here

let qb = QB()

qb {
    for x in ([5;2;0].AsQueryable()) do
    where (x > 1)
    sortBy x
    select x
    concat ([7;8;9].AsQueryable())
} |> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent reference for query expressions in F#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx

In particular, I think the following example from that page does what you want:

```
let query1 = query {
        for n in db.Student do
        select (n.Name, n.Age)
    }

let query2 = query {
        for n in db.LastStudent do
        select (n.Name, n.Age)
        }

query2.Union (query1)
```

Comment: I already know how to "Concat/Union" both queries, it is more of a philosophical question. Since it can be done already, why can't it be done using the traditional `yield!` used in other computation expressions such as `Seq` and `List`?